# Generic Enum parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a function which takes a specific type of enum value to determine a colour to pass as a prop to another function. I would like to be able to throw a different enum at my function. I have thought of generic type but TypeScript complains:

> AccountState' is not comparable to type 'T'.

```
enum AccountState {
  Active = 'Active',
  Deactivated = 'Deactivated'
}

const Indicator = (props: { state: AccountState }) => {
  let indicatorColor: string;

  switch (props.state) {
    case AccountState.Active:
      indicatorColor = 'green';
      break;
    case AccountState.Deactivated:
      indicatorColor = 'red';
      break;
  }

  return (
    <span
      style={{
        width: '10px',
        height: '10px',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        backgroundColor: indicatorColor,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

This way I am able to render `<Indicator state={Status.Active} />` however, I would also like to support this enum.

```
enum PaymentState {
  Paid = 'Paid',
  Unpaid = 'Unpaid',
  Pending = 'Pending'
}
```

I have tried the following

```
const Indicator = <T,>(props: { state: T }) => {
  let indicatorColor: string;

  switch (props.state) {
    case AccountState.Active: // AccountState' is not comparable to type 'T'.
    case PaymentState.Paid:
      indicatorColor = 'green';
      break;
    case AccountState.Deactivated:
    case PaymentState.Unpaid:
      indicatorColor = 'red';
      break;
  }

  return (
    <span
      style={{
        width: '10px',
        height: '10px',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        backgroundColor: indicatorColor,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put appropriate constraint for `T`:

```js
import React from 'react'

enum AccountState {
    Active = 'Active',
    Deactivated = 'Deactivated'
}

enum PaymentState {
    Paid = 'Paid',
    Unpaid = 'Unpaid',
    Pending = 'Pending'
}

type Union = AccountState | PaymentState

type Props = {
    state: Union
}

const Indicator = (props: Props) => {
    let indicatorColor: string;

    switch (props.state) {
        case AccountState.Active: {
            indicatorColor = 'green';
            break;
        }

        case AccountState.Deactivated: {
            indicatorColor = 'red';
            break;
        }

        case PaymentState.Paid: {
            indicatorColor = 'azure';
            break;
        }

        default: {
            indicatorColor = 'default value'
        }
    }

    return (
        <span
            style={{
                width: '10px',
                height: '10px',
                borderRadius: '50%',
                backgroundColor: indicatorColor,
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCpAOwFc8BBNNCW6mAZRhRiTgG8KcYXCYxgANz4BeAmMlJ8AGiEiAIsXESeSACZxZ+Dei07dZcgF8KVOngAKKAJ4ganbrwGrhj4PsO+5irkInAAqtRgKH4GBBFRfsrecPY0usDUAOax+KnU6VkW1pTkME5gfBHAENSxTCxs7jpwAD4pzq7sXDo2peV89jhgAM6xgiEiwx5IAFzh1NXUFMUULNRTcACS+cBoPNCxABRgQ8NzgxAjAJQGAHxeE8IANkjwGel7MNAAwhBP0HMplAMpkANy9ULDADuwBgaAAFnBjqcAHRTHQ3cahUJ7YZ8eqsLrTFHyKRzLHYynvXb7KC-f5QHKZIg0fDgx6UkQAIyIKAA1uzOXAVhycSg8aJmISmrwUcYMJIzOTkkLqZ8fn8DoYiOZBULubyBSqRCKhbiBh03N1ZYFlaLOWrafStQQUAAvWhENnGyk81BG+3CU2c3RITAoWhPGB2-UiR1fOmaxmGUPhyPwbRPWiKH3C5LB4REGCe2qHXMAHmGUSWgexUycL2k-ApsdCMN0MHhc3wAEYAAxgAAeSVrQvhSGAmXh0YI-aHI9b2K50FDUAQKHStDOBAArH2AKQLxfc9B85mE3TOqBzeMahnBReWYpCgD0t2SV3ZllBQA)

P.S. it is considered a good practice to wrap your `case` expressions into `{ ... }`

Comment: It's not always `AccountState`, it may be `PaymentState` or possibly more enums in the future.

Comment: I wonder wether a generic is necessary now. Maybe it should have been just `const Indicator = (props: { state: AccountState | PaymentState })`. What do you think? I do wonder whether this is a good approach once the state enums expand and I have lots of them.

Comment: You are right. You don't need generic. I made an update. All extra enums you can add to `Union`